# URLs in references run-offs (using bibitem)

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using the simple method of \bibitem  for my references, and am using the \url command to add links, however, there is only one URL that runs off the page when I view the PDF:

[image]

This is what I have in the .tex file:

```
` \bibitem{} Guillermo Peón, S., \& Rodríguez Brindis, M. (2014). Analyzing the Exchange Rate Pass-through in Mexico: Evidence Post Inflation Targeting Implementation. Revista Ensayos Sobre Política Económica, 32(74), 18-35. Recuperado 13 de febrero, 2015 de  \url{http://www.elsevier.es/es-revista-ensayos-sobre-politica-economica-387-resumen-analizando-el-traspaso-del-tipo-90339576}
```

If someone knows how to fix this run-off, I would appreciate the feedback!!

Comment: Please consider including a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which demonstrates your problem, to help us help you.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

You can allow a linebreak at the hyphen if you pass the correct option to the url package, which gets loaded by hyperref:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Or, if you use the `url` package without `hyperref`, just set the option when you load it:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

Comment: The [hyphens] option worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Juri.